# About learning Python online and motivations

Tags: python

I wanted to ask you something important to me.
I'm already learning python because I think is a good starter programming lenguage, and I'm learning Python at Codeacademy.
But the exercises sometimes have strange answers.. I really love computers, and I like programming, that's why I want to learn this.
One question, when you were learning Python, did you descouraged easily and did you think "Oh, was that the answer? I knew how to do it, but why didn't I think of that, would I be good programming? I cannot do nothing without a tutorial.." did any of you think of that?

What online page for learning Python would you recommend me? I know Codeacademy is very good, but some of the exercises I don't know how to do it, I don't care if I learn python in 2 or 3 weeks 3 hours-a-day, but I want a good page that explains correctly all that stuff.

I want to program games, I know that Python is not specially made for games but I need to start with a easy language and I like Python, but I need a better explanation page with exercises to do in that page because I want learn a good Python lenguage. What would you recommend me? How did you motivate yourself when you were learning Python? What did you think learning Python?

I'm sorry for the bad english and sorry 'cause this is not a "programming" question, but this is important for me and my future, so please forgive me.
Greetings and thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right...this is not a programming question.

Comment: this isn't really the kind of question to ask on this site.  but... start with a small project or goal or problem and start learning.  just make a fake site and give it functionality.  the best way to learn is by doing...

Comment: SO is not the place for this. This is not meant to be harsh, this site is for questions and answers to technical problems, not to start discussions on merits, motivations, and opinions.

Comment: It's a good question but unfortunately this just isn't the place to ask it.. so not to discourage you from learning to program, like with anything you're not gonna be good at it at first. it takes time but it's doable. the more you code the better you get!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876337/how-should-i-go-about-learning-python?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573135/python-progression-path-from-apprentice-to-guru?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710363/what-do-you-wish-youd-known-about-when-you-started-learning-python?lq=1

Comment: One suggestion for SO moderators...please close the question when it is unfit like this one but negative voting will definitely discourage the one when he/she is looking for encouragement.

Comment: Thank you for that Jack, but don't worry, it's my fault, this forum is for real programming questions, your answer encouraged me, cause now I know that other people had my problem and now they are good programmers, I understand the negative voting, it's just my fault, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this question is going to be closed soon but since I also faced the same problem when I started. I will give you short but quick tip:

Download-- thinking in python... (a book from green tea press)

---Study it

Go to Python docs...Refer to it frequently..

Test your programming skills using projects from projecteuler.net

Frequently test yourself.

Download pygame for games.

Read their tutorials.

Try to make games or add to the games for which you have source code.

Always try to improve.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I know that this is for programming question but I didn't know where to make this answer, and I say sorry to all the people.
I will download that and study, thanks for your big help!
And like I saw you faced the same problem, and I will try to motivate myself, the next questions from me are going to be from python.

Comment: Good luck in your endeavors.